# Poor performance of Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, ef-core-2.1

Consider we have an entity called FactValue, This entity has a relation with KPI entity and this relation is 1 to 1 (each FactValue has a KPI) and each KPI has a relation with Measure entity and this relation is 1 to n. So for each FactValue we have one KPI and n Measures.

I developed a panel for end user to write his own expressions over our database and I will execute that expression by DynamicExpressions. If we run a simple select query like :

```
FactValue.KPI.Measure.Average(it.MinimumValue)
```

it will be served with an iterative approach (For each tuple of FactValue-KPI it will execute a SQL query for retrieve the average of minimumvalues of Measures).
But obviously it can be done on a single query like:

```
select FactValue.FactValueId, avg(MinimumValue) 
from FactValue
inner join KPI on FactValue.KPIId = KPI.KPIId
inner join Measure on KPI.MeasureId = Measure.MeasureId
group by FactValueId
```

I checked it with simple Linq query, too (something like this):

```
var result = context.FactValue.KPI.Measure.Average(t=>t.MinimumValue)
```

But when I monitored the Profiler, it was the same.

Consider that I can't change the way of creating expression because it depends on end user and I have no control over it. So is there any way that I can handle it?

Comment: What EF is this? EF Core? I'm asking because EF6 always executes a single SQL query per LINQ query.

Comment: I developed on EF Core.

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest EF Core (2.1.2 currently). In general you are bound to EF Core query translator, which still is far from perfect. The only thing you can do (especially when you have no control over the queries) is to accept the inefficient implementation and wait for it to be improved by monitoring and upgrading to the newer EF Core releases.

Comment: I think so, let's wait and hope.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take another approach. Take a look at the linq examples http://linq101.nilzorblog.com/aggregate-operators.php#min-grouped

eg.
var categories = context.FactValue.GroupBy(fv => fv.FactValueId).Select(t => new {FactValueId = t.FactValueId, AverageMeasurement = t.Min(p => p.KPI.Measurement.MinimumValue)});

I did not test the above.

Just as a not this query does a group by on the entire FactValue table so as time goes by and the table grows performance will degrade. Even if you do database tweaks with indexes  etc...

Also in your one query you use 'Average' and in the other 'Min'

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, The Min method was a mistake of mine and I revised it. As I said I can't change the way of querying because indeed I don't write the queries and the end user will write them by some expressions.